# How to send rpc-command for new wallet with python?

Tags: python, rpc, cryptocurrency

I faced a problem. How can i send rpc command, using rpc accesses (ip, port, rpc_user, rpc_pass) to get a new wallet.
I tried to use this library, but connection hasn't established. I have no doubt that I can be stupid. Thank you!

```
from bitcoinrpc.authproxy import AuthServiceProxy, JSONRPCException
rpc_connection = AuthServiceProxy(f"http://{rpc_user}:{rpc_password}@{ip_addr}:{port}")
```